# C Programming - Nested Linked List issue with printing

Tags: c

I am writing an assignment for class and I am having a bit of an issue.  As with most programming classes, they don't always use best practices with setting up the variables and code and you have to get it to work.

Here is the setup:

link.h

```
//just showing the struct setup
typedef struct listCDT *listADT;
```

link.c

```
//just showing the struct setup as all the other functions work
typedef struct point {
   listElementT x; 
   struct point *next;
} myDataT;

struct listCDT {
    myDataT *start;     // myDataT *header;
    myDataT *end;       // myDataT *footer;
};
```

driver.c

```
//main is truncated to just the problem area
void main()
{
     listADT X, Y;
     X = NewList(); 
     Y = NewList();

     list_print_values(Y, "Y");
}

void list_print_values(listADT a, char *name)
{
        while (a != NULL)
        {
        printf("%d   ", *((*a)->start)->x););
        a = (&a)->end;
    }
    printf("\n");

    return;
}
```

driver.c is the only file that I have created and the only issue I am currently having is with printing the struct.  I get the following error:

```
>make
gcc  -c driver.c
driver.c: In function ‘list_print_values’:
driver.c:56:22: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   printf("%d   ", *((*a)->start)->x);
                      ^
driver.c:57:11: error: request for member ‘end’ in something not a structure or union
   a = (&a)->end;
           ^
make: *** [driver.o] Error 1
```

I have tried just about everything I can think of and I must be missing something simple?  Can anyone help?

Comment: You don't need to dereference when using `->` operator.

Comment: Normally, hafeez, I would tend to agree but:

> make
gcc  -c driver.c
driver.c: In function ‘list_print_values’:
driver.c:70:20: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   printf("%d   ", a->start->x);
                    ^
driver.c:71:8: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   a = a->end;
        ^
make: *** [driver.o] Error 1

Comment: Try `(a->start). x`

Comment: Are there functions in link.c that allow you to extract values from the list?  If so, you'll need to use those since driver.c doesn't know the definition of `struct listCDT`.

Answer (score 1):

Structure members are accessed by using either `.` or `->` operator. One is used with structure pointers and the other is used with structures.
In your case you are accessing members of a structure pointer, as you are using `->` you don't need to dereference.

```
printf("%d   ", (a->start)->x);
    a = a->end;
```

Assuming the `listElement` is of `type int` thus the format specifier `%d`.